# Building long-life background agent (more than 2 weeks) in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns, background-agents

I need long-term working background agent in wp7. 
I know that default and maximum life-cycle for such agents is 2 weeks. Also i got situation, when battery is critical low, all background agents are turning off.

So now i see only two workaround for this situation:

- i can restart background agent every time when my application is
  launched (but i have no warranty, that user will launch this
  application at least every 2 weeks)
- or i can use push notifications
  to turn on background agent.

Am i right? Are there any other workarounds?

Comment: Bear in mind that background agents just plain do not run on the lower spec devices, so it might be worth explaining your use case for the agent to determine if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to use a push notification to turn on your background agent.  If your app is not running at the time your notification comes through, your only options are to display Toast or change the Start Menu tile.

Your first thought around restarting your background agent is what you will need to do to refresh.  One thing you might want to consider is, in your background agent, keeping track of the last time it was refreshed by someone opening the app.  Then, if you're getting close to the end of that lifecycle, you can change your tile image or text to reflect that the user needs to refresh.  I've seen a couple apps that do this.

You have to keep in mind that your background agent is not guaranteed to be active.  It can be shut down by low battery or user request without ever telling you, or your app.

Comment: ok, what about situation when battery critical low, and background agent also turns off. How do you think, what is best solution to restore it's working ?

Comment: I could be wrong on this, but I think if it goes into battery critical, once the critical is turned off, the agents that were active should be reactivated.  You should renew your agent status on every startup of your application regardless.  That way, the two-week countdown is reset.

Comment: But it does not restores. Maybe i am doing something wrong. Any way i'll check, thank you!